# Run-time display management on Linux without X?

Tags: linux, display-settings

Is there a way to manage displays (change resolution/rotation/output toggling) on KMS-enabled hardware with a GUI-less Linux installation? As I understand it, all the driver magic that makes this possible was moved from X11 drivers into the kernel drivers over the past decade or so, so I'd expect there's a way to manage it, but haven't found anything close to providing `xrandr`-like features.

What I want is to use full resolution and proper rotation on external display when connected, and be able to revert back when using a laptop's built-in LCD.

Comment: Have a look at `fbset` or other framebuffer tools. Not sure how much rotation and different outputs are supported, if they are, you may need other tools to access the kernel API.